# Hard Fault when optimization level 1 is enabled (FreeRTOS)

Tags: c, embedded, freertos

I have the following function used to test the file system (yaffs2). It is called by a FreeRTOS task with a stack size of 65535. In debug mode, everything appears to work fine, but when I enable -O1, I get a hard fault immediately after printing "Testing filesystem...".

I tried changing the test size to a much lower value, thinking maybe there is a memory issue (note that the FreeRTOS heap is 7MB wide), but nothing changed. Any ideas what might be causing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "yaffs_trace.h"
#include "yaffsfs.h"

int fs_test(void)
{
    int fd;
    int test_size = 1000000;
    const char path[] = "nand/testfile.dat";
    int pattern = 0x55;
    uint8_t *test;
    uint8_t *test_read;
    uint32_t start_time, stop_time;

    DEBUG_PRINT("Testing filesystem...\n");

    fd = yaffs_open(path, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);

    if(fd < 0) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("cannot create test file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    test = pvPortMalloc(test_size);
    test_read = pvPortMalloc(test_size);

    if(test == NULL || test_read == NULL) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("not enough memory\n");
        vPortFree(test);
        vPortFree(test_read);
        yaffs_close(fd);
        yaffs_rm(path);
        return -2;
    }

    memset(test, pattern, test_size);

    start_time = xTaskGetTickCount();
    yaffs_write(fd, test, test_size);
    yaffs_close(fd);
    stop_time = xTaskGetTickCount();

    DEBUG_PRINTF("Average write speed = %d kB/s\n", test_size / (stop_time-start_time));

    fd = yaffs_open(path, O_RDWR, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);

    if(fd < 0) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("cannot open test file\n");
        vPortFree(test);
        vPortFree(test_read);
        yaffs_close(fd);
        yaffs_rm(path);
        return -1;
    }

    start_time = xTaskGetTickCount();
    yaffs_read(fd, test_read, test_size);
    yaffs_close(fd);
    stop_time = xTaskGetTickCount();

    DEBUG_PRINTF("Average read speed = %d kB/s\n", test_size / (stop_time-start_time));

    if (!memcmp(test, test_read, test_size))
        DEBUG_PRINT("file integrity test successful\n");
    else
        DEBUG_PRINT("file integrity test failed!\n");

    yaffs_rm(path);

    vPortFree(test);
    vPortFree(test_read);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ? Please set compiler warnings to be errors. Do you get _any_ compiler warnings? Please be more specific. What system are you using? What controller are you programming for? Why are there no `#include`s?  What compiler are you using? `note that the FreeRTOS heap is 7MB wide` How are you checking that? How much memory do you have available?

Comment: @KamilCuk I am programming a MicroSemi SmartFusion2 SoC. The system has 8MB of RAM, and I set the heap size to 7MB in freertos config file. I use GNU ARM Cross C Compiler. Edited the question to include `#include`s. The only warnings I get are shift-count-overflows in a YAFFS header.

Comment: Sure. Where does `fs_open` and `DEBUG_PRINT` come from? Have implemented them yourself? What libraries are you using? FreeRTOS are only `v*` `x*` functions

Comment: `DEBUG_PRINT` is my implementation, it is simply a macro for TX of the appropriate UART interface, and  `fs_open` is also a macro for `yaffs_open`.

Comment: `also a macro for yaffs_open`  Please create a full [MCVE]. You can't post a code without "my implementation" and expect others to know what's going on. Still - where does `yaffs_open` come from? What libraries are you using and from where? In particular, if that is the library found on first hits on google, did you call `yaffs_StartUp` an `yaffs_mount`?

Comment: Yes, yaffs2 is taken from https://yaffs.net/. It works very well in other functions, but only this one generates a hard fault.

Comment: _" immediately after printing "Testing filesystem...""_ - so before the `return -1` or on the `return`, or is your description "_immediately_" not that literal?  Failure on return often indicates stack corruption from a buffer overrun for example.  You have a debugger do you - that is the way to debug this - too much unseen and other people's code to diagnose it here.

Comment: @Clifford Not that literal. I checked with debugger and it doesn't hit any of the return statements, usually throws the fault around memset statement.

Comment: 65535 is not a valid stack size.  It should be a multiple of 8.

Comment: If the debug output is buffered, the output of the debug message and the actual fault could be entirely unrelated and the issue may not be in this code at all.  If you have other threads (suggested by use of an RTOS), it could be as easily one thread stomping on the stack of another.  As it is there is just too little information here to _debug by correspondence_.  Common causes of differences between `-O0` and `-O1` behaviour are use of undefined behaviour and unitialised variables.

Comment: What processor is this?  On Cortex-M a "hard-fault" is a default handler when more specific exceptions are not enabled.  Enabling MemManage, Bus and Usage faults, or inspecting the SHCSR may provide useful information to narrow down the cause.  Then you'd also want to inspect the call stack to determine where this is actually coming from.  Your question should either provide the kind of debugging information that anyone would need if they were debugging this, or you should be asking how to debug it rather than asking what the bug is, because I doubt it is specifically in this code.

Comment: "_It works very well in other functions,..._" - would that also be in _other threads_?  Have you implemented `yaffs_lock()` and `yaffs_unlock()` to ensure reentrancy?  yaffs also uses malloc/free internally by default for memory allocation - are your implementations for those also re-entrant, or have you changed the default alloc/free?  Just reading the documentation: https://yaffs.net/sites/yaffs.net/files/YaffsDirect.pdf §7.3 _RTOS Integration Interface_

Comment: @Clifford The SmartFusion 2 device uses an ARM Cortex-M3 Processor. I implemented the lock, unlock, malloc and free functions appropriately using the RTOS functions. What you said about thread stomping may be the issue, but as you said in this case, I am not sure how to debug it.

Comment: It does not mention _SmartFusion 2_ in the question.  You need to edit the question to include relevant information - don't expect anyone to have to read the comments for that information.

Comment: @Clifford It appears you were onto something. I disabled all other tasks and it worked without any problems. Then I enabled them one by one, testing each step multiple times, and one of them definitely creates the issue.